# request for member 'scale' in '((Circle*)this)->Circle::_radius', which is of non-class type 'double'|

Tags: c++

```
void Circle::scale(const Point& center, double s)
{
    _radius = _radius.scale(center, s);

}
```

Can someone explain it to me why this will not work? This is the error I get. 
request for member 'scale' in '((Circle*)this)->Circle::_radius', which is of non-class type 'double'

```
class Circle : public Shape
{
public:

    Circle(Point center, double radius,
            Color edgeColor=Color::black,
            Color fillColor=Color::transparent);
    virtual void scale(const Point& center, double s);
    virtual void translate(double x, double y);
    virtual void draw(Graphics& g) const;
    virtual void fill(Graphics& g) const;
    virtual void print(std::ostream& os) const;

   virtual Shape* clone() const {return new Circle(*this);}

    virtual RectangularArea boundingBox() const;
    virtual void get(std::istream& in);

private:

    Point  _center;
    double  _radius;
};
```

Comment: A double doesn't have such operator, you probably meant `_radius = scale(center, s);`.

Comment: This is the error I get when I tried that :void value not ignored as it ought to be

Comment: It would help to see the class declaration for `Circle`.

Comment: Added the header file

Comment: What do you expect that line to do? A `double` is just that, it doesn't have member functions/methods. You need to write the code that does the scaling.

Comment: Scaling code is already written in another file.

Comment: And how is that function supposed to be called? does it have this signature: `double scale(double x, double factor)`? You could also simply multiply: `_radius *= s;`

Comment: Ok your idea about _radius *=s; worked. Thanks a lot. I am sure my professor will take off points since I am not using the pointer. Thanks a lot though.

Answer (score 0):

did you check the return type of the 'scale' function?
First of all, it's a void function, so it doesn't return anything. But here you want to give _radius the value that 'scale' returns... And,also, it's is a member function, so it must be called from a Circle object, and you're calling it from a double... 
Hope it helped you

Comment: I am not allowed to change the function to double.. it has to stay virtual void

Comment: Yes but what does 'scale' do? What is its prototype? If you can't change its return value, it's not allowed to assign _radius.scale in _radius...